# Hide certain methods from the codeception debug output

Tags: codeception

When launching the tests with the --debug flag it shows every method which is executed, is it at all possible to exclude certain methods from appearing in this log?

So you could hide super repetitive methods from appearing in it, like the ones in below in red

[image]

On the codeception site I see the following options but it doesn't help in my case:

```
Verbosity modes:

codecept run -v:
codecept run --steps: print step-by-step execution
codecept run -vv: print steps and debug information
codecept run --debug: alias for -vv
codecept run -vvv: print Codeception-internal debug information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to hide certain methods, but you could reduce amount of output by extracting repetetive code to [helper methods](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers).

In your example it looks like you executed 5 actions twice, so you could extract them to helper method and add it to tests/_suppor/Helper/Acceptance.php.

```php
public function waitForPageLoadToComplete()
{
  $webDriver = $this->getModule('WebDriver');
  $webDriver->waitForElementNotVisible('#loadingPage', 60);
  $webDriver->waitForElementNotVisible('#ajaxloading_mask', 60);
  $webDriver->waitForJs('return $.active == 0', 60);
  $webDriver->waitForJs('return document.readyStaty == "complete"', 60);
  $webDriver->waitForJs('return !!window.jQUery && window.jQUery.active == 0', 60);
}
```

Then each call to helper method would produce only one line of output:

```
I wait for page load to complete
I wait for page load to complete
I grab multiple
```